# End RegEx after certain digit

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am working on a filter based upon browser version and am having a little trouble. It has to be in RegEx which loves to encompass everything possible.

I want to select:
12.0
8.0
18.0.1025.168

The problem I am having (looking at the 12.0 specifically however it is a problem for all 3) is that it is selecting things other than 12.0 as well. I have been trying to use negated sets and non-capturing groups however it just isn't quite working.

Currently I have: ((?:18.0.1025.168[^.]|(12.0)[^.]|(?:8.0)[^.]))

I have used \d in the negated sets however it seems as though I have to choose \d or . because it does not allow for special characters within the set.

Things that I need to make sure are not selected include any variation of the following, (the 9's could be any number)
9.12.0
912.0
92.09
12.0.9

Any input of what I should look into or another symbol I could use would be greatly appreciated. Also, if needed I can break this into 3 different formulas that will all fire however would like to avoid that is possible

Comment: Can you provide your code, the input(s), and actual vs expected output(s)?

Comment: This is just for a Google Analytics filter, we are trying to exclude these browser versions however have not been able to select them without also selecting other browser versions as well.

The format for RegEx in GA is fairly simple as it runs each session through the requirements to determine if it should be excluded or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `(\A|^)(12.0|8.0|18.0.1025.168)($|\z)`

Comment: MBaas, that seems to work perfectly! Thank you!!  


I had tried to use the ^ and $ characters before however was having trouble. Do you know why exactly it works with the (\A|^) and ($|\z)?

Comment: In my tests it failed with ^$ because these are only start/end of string, so I added beginning/end of line to handle these cases, too :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks again for your help! what do you use to test your RegEx? I was using http://www.regexr.com/ but it doesn't recognize \A or \z and just has them as escaped characters.

Comment: I'm using RegExBuddy (http://www.regexbuddy.com/ ) for several yrs now. It's shareware, but has never disappointed me. You can easily construct expressions, test them and build code for various programming languages using these statements.